# SQL select Query to get one value from two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have following table

```
[From] |[to]
ABC  | DBC
DBC     |ABC
```

I need to get a new column as following

```
[From]  [to]   [seg]
ABC      DBC    ABCDBC
DBC      ABC    ABCDBC
```

how to write this select query from above table

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at [ask]. Are those columns text columns, and `[seg]` should be the combination of `[from]` and `[to]`. Err, no, why is `[seg]` `ABCDBC` in the second row? Please explain the logic of what you are trying to do. And please show what you have tried so far and how it failed (we're no free code writing service).

Comment: As mentioned by René, your second row doesn't make sense. Also, do you have any special requirements for handling nulls? What if `From` is null? Would the `seg` also be null?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you actually using here? You have tagged 2 versions and in this case it does matter.

Comment: Actually I'm using  SQL-server 2014, sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1):

[sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) unfortunately doesn't support the `least` and `greatest` functions (at least, not as far as I am aware), but you can easily emulate this behavior use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT [from],
       [to],
       CASE WHEN [from] < [to] THEN CONCAT([from], [to])
            ELSE CONCAT([to], [from])
       END AS seg
FROM   mytable
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae370/4/0)**

**EDIT:**

As per the comments, older version of SQL-Server do not support the `concat` function. If you really need to use such old databases, you could use the `+` operator instead:

```
SELECT [from],
       [to],
       CASE WHEN [from] < [to] THEN [from] + [to]
            ELSE [to] + [from]
       END AS seg
FROM   mytable
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae370/5/0)**

Comment: Another problem is the multiple version of SQL tagged. 2008 doesn't support `CONCAT` :/ In fact, the comment on the other answer suggests it's SQL2008 in use.

Comment: @DavidG I didn't even think to check such an outdated database, thanks! I've edited my answer and showed how the `+` operator could be used instead if you need to.

Comment: And now OP says it works, but the other comment implies that is impossible. I'm so confused!

Comment: @DavidG OP just edited the question and rettaged it so that [tag:sql-server-2014] is the only version there. I guess that this implies that the original tagging was a mistake.

Comment: Yeah, but how does the error *concat' is not a recognized built-in function* happen?!

Comment: Yes it was a mistake so sorry for that @Mureinik, BTW correct one is with +